# Create queue on ElasticMQ startup without config file

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, elastic-mq

Well, I am wondering if it's possible creating the queue on container startup but without the config file, because at work we use an internal tool for CI, and can just set some environment variables and we are forced to rewrite the entrypoint command in the CI config file. The reason of that is that the CI config file does NOT have access to the CI workspace and its environment variables or files like a possible elasticmq-custom.conf, so it wouldn't be possible using that.
The CI config file is like this:

```yaml
schemaVersion: 2.0
image: docker://docker.io/softwaremill/elasticmq-native
host: QUEUE_URL
ports:
  - name: QUEUE_PORT
    default: 9325
commands:
  # here I would set some environment variables that can be accessed by the new start command
  - /sbin/tini -- /opt/docker/bin/elasticmq-native-server -Dconfig.file=/opt/elasticmq.conf -Dlogback.configurationFile=/opt/logback.xml
```

The goal would be creating the queue using the commands above, any idea?